# Substitute variables in strings like console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace, console.log

I want to substitute variables in a string like `console.log` does.
What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
let str = 'My %s is %s.';

replaceStr(string, /* args */) {
    // I need help with defining this function
};

let newStr = replaceStr(str, 'name', 'Jackie');
console.log(newStr);
// output => My name is Jackie.

/*
   This is similar to how console.log does:
   // console.log('I\'m %s.', 'Jack');
   // => I'm Jack.
*/
```

I am not able to figure out how to do that. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore What I want to achieve is not what template literals offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could prototype it to the `String` object. Something like this:

```
String.prototype.sprintf = function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var args = arguments;

    return this.replace(/%s/g, function() {
        return args[counter++];
    });
};

let str = 'My %s is %s.';
str = str.sprintf('name', 'Alex');
console.log(str); // 'My name is Alex'
```

Comment: Yes, this is a very nice way.

Comment: Glad i could help a bit :)

Comment: `console` can do much more than `%s`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#Using_string_substitutions

Answer (score 2):

You can use spread operator (ES6):

```
function replaceStr(string, ...placeholders) {
    while (placeholders.length > 0) {
         string = string.replace('%s', placeholders.shift());
    }

    return string;
}
```

EDIT: Based on lexith's answer, we can avoid the explicit loop:

```
function replaceStr(string, ...placeholders) {
    var count = 0;
    return string.replace(/%s/g, () => placeholders[count++]);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of that, but I was hoping for a method without using loops. Is that even possible?

Comment: See lexith's answer for < ES6 (or even >=).

Comment: @AnonymousGroup Added a solution based on lexith's answer that avoids loop and is concise thanks to ES6 things (spread operator, arrow function)

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares Have you tried that? This doesn't work as intended. :/
Lexith's answer seems to be the right one.

Comment: I tried and it worked, but in a browser that supports ES6. Lexith's answer is < ES6. It might be the reason.

Comment: You can more accurately replicate `console.log` by appending any remaining arguments. You can also use unshift with replace:
```function replaceStr(string, ...placeholders) {
    const replaced = string.replace(/%s/g, () => placeholders.shift());
    return [replaced, ...placeholders].join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If hope you want to have custom logger function.
`console.log` can replace `%s`, with below approach your custom function gets full feature set of console.log and its more efficient.

```
function myLogger() {
   if(logEnabled) {
      // you can play with arguments for any customisation's
      // arguments[0] is first string
      // prepend date in log  arguments[0] =  (new Date().toString()) + arguments[0] ;
      console.log.apply(console, arguments);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function replaceStr(string, ...placeholders) {
    const replaced = string.replace(/%s/g, () => placeholders.shift());
    return [replaced, ...placeholders].join(' ');
}
```

This will append any remaining placeholders to the string to more accurately replicate `console.log`.